# What's wrong with my Class Library? 'Fatal Execution Engine Error'

Tags: c#, class-library, autodesk, autodesk-navisworks

I am trying to make an Plug In for Navisworks manage that will rename a batch of selected clashes with a prefix or suffix. I am running this on Visual Studio.

```
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api;
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash;

namespace ClashTestNameModifier
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Open the Navisworks document
            string modelPath = @"C:\path\to\your\model.nwd";
            Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application app = new Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application();
            Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Document doc = app.OpenFile(modelPath);

            // Get the selected clash tests
            Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash.TestsData clashTestsData = doc.GetClash().TestsData;
            SavedItemCollection selectedTests = clashTestsData.Tests.Value.GetSelectedItems();

            if (selectedTests.Count == 0)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("No clash tests selected.");
                return;
            }

            // Modify the clash test names
            string prefix = "New Prefix ";
            string suffix = " - Suffix";

            foreach (SavedItem testItem in selectedTests)
            {
                ClashTest test = clashTestsData.TestsDataArray[testItem.Index];
                test.DisplayName = prefix + test.DisplayName + suffix;
            }

            // Save the modified document
            doc.SaveFile(modelPath);

            // Close the document
            doc.Close();

            // Dispose of the application
            app.Dispose();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Clash test names modified successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get the following errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAeT9.png)

[image: IMAGE 2]

Comment: You're showing (a picture of) multiple error messages.  Is there one specific error message which isn't clear to you?  Please update the question to indicate that specific error message, which line of code it references, and what you are asking about that error.

Comment: That are compiler errors not runtime error. So you didn't run the program it fails already when compiling. For a starter is looks like you missing a reference to the "Autodesk.Navisworks" stuff you are using. Its not enough to put a using statement at the beginning of the file you must reference the needed assembly.

Comment: David, I'm not sure if I am getting the first error because it can't reference the Autodesk.Navisworks.Api or because of a syntax error.

Ralf,  I do have the "Autodesk.Navisworks dll files referenced as seen on the the solution explorer.

Comment: @PAPIWARBUX: What indication do you have that there is a syntax error or a problem when referencing the library?  Perhaps it's referencing a different version of the library?  The "first error" is simply telling you that there is no constructor for `Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application` which takes 0 arguments.  The code shown is expecting such a constructor to exist.  Can you indicate where in any documentation for `Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application` that such a constructor exists?

Comment: The code as written seems to be based on the olden COM Automation api.  Autodesk however created a much more friendly .NET wrapper, unfortunately using the exact same namespace and class names.  The error messages look consistent with that new api. A developer guide [is here](https://apidocs.co/apps/navisworks/2018/87317537-2911-4c08-b492-6496c82b3ed0.htm)

Answer (score 0):

To create a plugin for Navisworks, you need to start by creating a class library project in the .dll format. The simplest type of plugin is `AddinPlugin`, which can be found in the `Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Plugins` namespace. For more information on creating Navisworks plugins, you can refer to the link provided below.

https://apidocs.co/apps/navisworks/2018/87317537-2911-4c08-b492-6496c82b3ed6.htm

I have tried to edit your code so that it works, but one issue is that the Navisworks Clash API does not currently support the retrieval of selected tests from the UI. The documentation states that the UI part of the Clash API is still underdeveloped.

```cs
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash;
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api;
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Plugins;

namespace ClashTestNameModifier
{
    [Plugin("ClashTestNameModifier.PAPI", "PAPI", DisplayName = "ClashTest Name Modifier")]
    [AddInPlugin(AddInLocation.AddIn)]
    public class ClashTestNameModifierAddinPlugin : AddInPlugin
    {
        public override int Execute(params string[] parameters)
        {
            // Open the Navisworks document
            string modelPath = @"C:\path\to\your\model.nwd";
            Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Document doc = Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application.MainDocument;
            doc.OpenFile(modelPath);

            // Get all clash tests
            Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash.DocumentClashTests clashTestsData = doc.GetClash().TestsData;

            // Clash API does not support the selected tests yet.
            // But, assume that selected tests are found with a method
            SavedItemCollection selectedTests = FindSelectedTests(clashTestsData);

            // Modify the clash test names
            string prefix = "New Prefix ";
            string suffix = " - Suffix";

            foreach(SavedItem testItem in selectedTests)
            {
                var test = testItem as ClashTest;
                clashTestsData.TestsEditDisplayName(testItem, prefix + test.DisplayName + suffix);
            }

            // Save the modified document
            doc.SaveFile(modelPath);

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to run this on a console application, you may need to reference and use the `Autodesk.Navisworks.Automation` assembly. With Automation, it's also possible to invoke a plug-in and receive a reply in the form of a status code. For additional information, please visit the following link:

https://apidocs.co/apps/navisworks/2018/87317537-2911-4c08-b492-6496c82b3ed7.htm